# Rescale in Illustrator and maintain proportions in After Effects?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, adobe-after-effects, scale

I ran into a problem.

I've a character in Illustrator that is animated in After Effects. I've setup and animated the character already and now my client decided that everything needs to be bigger. It get's pixelated and blurred. Is there any way for me to scale the character in Illustrator and keep the proportions? The character gets distorted when I rescale. Or do I have to make everything from scratch?

*Bicubic scale isn't helpful as the images have to be as sharp as in Illustrator.*

Comment: You can scale proportionally in Illustrator by holding down the Shift key as you click and drag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, is an illustrator file, so is vector, there is no reason why you shouldn't use "continuously rasterize" on each vector layer, that should fix your sharpness problem.

[image]

[image]

About the scale, just parent all to a single null, and scale this null to the new size you need.

Answer (score 0):

If your character is made of raster objects then you are out of luck.
If your image made of vector objects you just need to make sure to go to

Preferences->General-> and turn on "Scale Strokes and Effects"

Also I would recommend looking into a rigging academy because it gets into the details of how to import from Ai to AE. https://www.schoolofmotion.com/rigging-academy/ (It costs money) If you still need help.